# Looking for a short way to generate subclass (that would be created into a new file), with parent class' methods included in it (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, code-generation

Will use following example to explain.

Existing python file (a.py) contains one class:

```
class A:
    def method1(self, par1, par2='e'):
        # some code here
        pass
    def method2(self, parA):
        # some code here
        pass
    def method3(self, a, b, c):
        # lots of code here
        pass
    def anothermethod(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A().anothermethod()
```

Now, there is a need to create another py file (b.py), which would contain subclass (class B) of class A. 
And there is a need to have all the methods included (all inherited from parent class), but without 
implementation in it. Result might look like:

```
class B(A):
    def method1(self, par1, par2='e'):
        # empty here; ready to override
        pass
    def method2(self, parA):
        # empty here; ready to override
        pass
    def method3(self, a, b, c):
        # empty here; ready to override
        pass
    def anothermethod(self):
        # empty here; ready to override
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    B().anothermethod()
```

Having described the example, the question is: how could one generate last mentioned (skeleton-like) py file? So that after generating you can just open generated file and start right away with filling specific implementation.

There must be a shorter way, 1-2 line solution. Maybe it is already solvable by some existing functionality within modules already provided by Python (Python 3)? 





***Edit (2018 Mar 14).*** Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152537/4958287 (though was looking for short and already existing solution here). Will have to settle with longer solution for now -- will include its rough version here, maybe it would be helpful to someone else:

```
import inspect
from a import A

def construct_skeleton_subclass_from_parent(subcl_name, parent_cl_obj):
    """
    subcl_name : str 
        Name for subclass and 
        file to be generated.
    parent_cl_obj : obj (of any class to create subclass for)
        Object of parent class.
    """

    lines = []
    subcl_name = subcl_name.capitalize()

    parent_cl_module_name = parent_cl_obj.__class__.__module__
    parent_cl_name = parent_cl_obj.__class__.__name__

    lines.append('from {} import {}'.format(parent_cl_module_name, parent_cl_name))
    lines.append('')
    lines.append('class {}({}):'.format(subcl_name, parent_cl_name))
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(parent_cl_obj, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
        args = inspect.signature(method)
        args_others = str(args).strip('()').strip()
        if len(args_others) == 0:
            lines.append('    def {}(self):'.format(name))
        else:
            lines.append('    def {}(self, {}):'.format(name, str(args).strip('()')))
        lines.append('        pass')
        lines.append('')

    #...
    #lines.append('if __name__ == \'__main__\':')
    #lines.append('    ' + subcl_name + '().anothermethod()')
    #...

    with open(subcl_name.lower() + '.py', 'w') as f:
        for c in lines:
            f.write(c + '\n')

a_obj = A()
construct_skeleton_subclass_from_parent('B', a_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of methods and each of their signatures using the `inspect` module:

```
import a
import inspect

for name, method in inspect.getmembers(a.A, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    args = inspect.signature(method)
    print("    def {}({}):".format(name, args))
    print("        pass")
    print()
```